# SQLite Code Analysis C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, parsing, tokenize, code-analysis

I was wondering, how can i parse a SQLIte Query, and tokenize it in order to get the future to be affected entries after the execution of the query, to be able to set policies on a single SQLite database?

So far i have created a project that accepts modules. And there is a single SQLite database. My goal is to create a Controller which will receive the queries from each Module, and essentially check if this module is allowed to change a particular thing in the database.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Is there any library for this or something? I have searched a lot but didn't find any solution in 6 months.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Sure, the question _"How to find out which tables and rows an SQL query is going to hit"_ is answerable, but the answer will prove not to be practical. What _exactly_ are you trying to do? What are those "modules" and who creates them? There's a reason (for example) plugin systems expose an API, and not the raw data source.

Comment: It seems you are right. I was so focused about parsing the sql queries, by completely ignoring the possibility of creating an api  that would do this job. Silly me i guess.

Comment: This sounds similar to the [authorize callback](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/set_authorizer.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to parse SQLite queries is to let SQLite itself run them.

If you proceed the SQL statement with [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html), you'll get a result set containing the virtual machine instructions (*without* actually executing the query).  If you look at the rows that have `opcode = 'TableLock'`, the `p4` column will give you the name of the table affected.

Answer (score 1):

A library? Probably not. Software you wish for rarely exists.  That usually means you have to build it yourself or go without.

What you need is

- a parser of SQL queries,
- a parser of user-capabilities (which user is allowed to update which tables/columns,
- a SQL analyzer that can tell which user might be running a bit of SQL, and which tables/fields the SQL is modifying.

Doing all of this is straightforward using classic static analysis techniques.  You may have to go learn this if you want to code your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

To set policies on a database, you can use a [Compile-Time Authorization Callback](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/set_authorizer.html):

> At various points during the compilation process, as logic is being created to perform various actions, the authorizer callback is invoked to see if those actions are allowed. The authorizer callback should return SQLITE_OK to allow the action, SQLITE_IGNORE to disallow the specific action but allow the SQL statement to continue to be compiled, or SQLITE_DENY to cause the entire SQL statement to be rejected with an error.
>   […]
>   An authorizer is used when preparing SQL statements from an untrusted source, to ensure that the SQL statements do not try to access data they are not allowed to see, or that they do not try to execute malicious statements that damage the database.
>   […]
>   Applications that need to process SQL from untrusted sources might also consider lowering resource limits using [sqlite3_limit()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/limit.html) and limiting database size using the [max_page_count](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_max_page_count) PRAGMA in addition to using an authorizer.

However, you'd have to extended your C# database driver to make this API available.